# Combine descriptive stats with Anova summary and write in same Excel sheet

Tags: r, excel

I have 40 Answers (Q1_Biodiv,Q1_Poll, ....) in a survey where I want to analyze the social descriptors for each answer.
I want to write out the descriptive results of my data and combine it with the summary results of an ANOVA for several answers .
Then I would like to write everything in the same Excel sheet.

My Data is like that:

```
Q1_Biodiv   Q1_Poll gender2 edu3    job3    country2
2   2   1   1   1   1
3   3   1   1   1   1
2   2   1   1   2   1
2   5   1   1   1   1
2   5   1   1   1   2
5   5   2   1   2   2
3   3   1   1   2   2
5   5   2   1   1   1
5   5   2   1   1   1
3   3   1   1   2   1
3   3   1   1   1   2
2   2   1   1   1   2
```

I tried this code:
I use the library(WriteXLS) and library(broom)

```
db1$job <- factor(db1$job)
job <- tabular( Q1_Biodiv+Q1_Poll ~ job* (mean+sd), data=db1

db1$education <- factor(db1$education)
edu<- tabular( Q1_Biodiv+Q1_Poll ~ education* (mean+sd), data=db1 )

db1$gender <- factor(db1$gender)
ge <- tabular( Q1_Biodiv+Q1_Poll ~ gender* (mean+sd), data=db1)

db1$country <- factor(db1$country)
co <- tabular( Q1_Biodiv+Q1_Poll~country* (mean+sd), data=db1)

####### ANOVA
av11 <- anova(lm(Q1_Biodiv~job+edu+gender+country,data=db1))
av11<-tidy(av11)

# save everything to the same excel sheet in the right order
# Dosen't work with this
WriteXLS(av1, "descriptives.xlsx")
```

Can somebody be so kind to help me with getting done with the whole task???
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: First of all, your ANOVA block creates an av11 object, but you are passing an unknown object av1 to WriteXLS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package WriteXLS, but I note in the package documentation that you need to have a working installation of Perl on your machine to use it. The documentation says that you can run a function to check if Perl is installed. That might be a good place to start. The function is WriteXLS::testPerl().